# Intel Graphics - Conflicting libcairo2 package

Tags: apt, dpkg, intel-graphics, 16.10

After attempted installation with the Intel Graphics Update Tool for Linux OS, `dpkg` is failing to upgrade `libcairo2` and `libcairo2:i386`. Is there any fix available?

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libcairo2 libcairo2:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1.193 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4.096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [J/n] 
(Reading database ... 342251 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libcairo2_1.15.2-0intel1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcairo2:amd64 (1.15.2-0intel1) over (1.15.2-0intel1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9ZMnio/0-libcairo2_1.15.2-0intel1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libcairo2/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libcairo2:amd64
Preparing to unpack .../1-libcairo2_1.15.2-0intel1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libcairo2:i386 (1.15.2-0intel1) over (1.15.2-0intel1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9ZMnio/1-libcairo2_1.15.2-0intel1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libcairo2/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libcairo2:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9ZMnio/0-libcairo2_1.15.2-0intel1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9ZMnio/1-libcairo2_1.15.2-0intel1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Backup the two files in question, then rerun the update.

Comment: Please see the answers [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124290/apt-get-error-trying-to-overwrite-shared-filename-which-is-different-from-ot)  they might be helpful

Comment: Guess I can drop it as answer for you vote then?

Comment: Of course. I was just thinking of that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup the file in question:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/doc/libcairo2/changelog.Debian.gz /usr/share/doc/libcairo2/changelog.Debian.gz.backup
```

Then rerun the update. see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124290/apt-get-error-trying-to-overwrite-shared-filename-which-is-different-from-ot) for more details.